# How to add external data file into developing R package?

Tags: r, r-package

I am building my R packages in Rstudio, I ran into some unexpected problem when I tired to create package' vignette. when I hit build/load panel in Rstudio, I got vignette error, while package's documentation was created. To possibly solve vignette error I got, I have to add external data to my packages, use this data to compile package vignette accordingly. I used `devtools::install()` command to install my packages, but `inst/` directory is not created. `extdata` must be located in `inst` directory. I also used `devtools::use_data()` to add my data from my PC, but I can't able to add my external data. How can I load external data for my packages ?  I think I should not manually create `extdata` and put external data over there. Why `inst/` was not created when I used `devtools::install()` ? How to add set of csv files as external data into my packages ?

This is the toy helper function I am going to use in my vignette to read external data :

```
myFunc <- function(myDir, ...) {
  files <- list.files(myDir, full.names = TRUE, "\\.csv$")
  readMe <- lapply(files, read.csv)
  return(readMe)
}
```

This is the first time I build R packages, getting some common error. My apology if my questions is not well stated.

to find files in `inst/`, I need to use `system.file()`, but I don't have this directory, plus `myFunc` accept file directory to to grab the files and read them as .csv, this is toy code chunk could be executed in vignette file :

````
```{r}
library(myPkg)
file.1 <- system.file("extdata", "xxx.csv", "myPkg")
file.2 <- system.file("extdata", "yyy.csv", "myPkg")
myFunc(list(file.1, file.2))

```
````

How can I load external data to my packages in order to compile package vignette by using this data ? Why `inst/` not created when I hit `devtools::install()` ? Can anyone help me how to do this ?Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should manually create `inst/extdata/file.csv` in the base directory for your project (where `DESCRIPTION` is). You can put all the files you want to access in that directory.

Then to get the files in function examples or your vignette:

```
files <- lapply(list.files(system.file('extdata', package = 'my_package'), full.names = TRUE), read.csv)
```

`system.file()` returns the path to the `extdata` folder, then `list.files()` will create a vector of all the files in `extdata`. Finally, running `lapply()` with `read.csv()` should read the contents of all the files into a single list for you.

Comment: I think inst/ directory can be created by Rstudio automatically when I installed my packages. I checked other people' package in github.  Plus, my data could be multiple csv files, where system.file() only find single file. How can I make this more programmatic ? Any better idea please ?

Comment: Maybe RStudio can, but it works just as well for me when I just make the folder manually. I've updated the code to account for all the files though. Does this help?

Comment: If I need to find list of csv file by using system.file(), how can I make this more programmatic ?

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by "more programmatic". Currently, `system.file()` returns the path to the `extdata` folder, then `list.files()` will create a vector of all the files in `extdata`. Finally, running `lapply()` with `read.csv()` should read the contents of all the files into a single list for you. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Ahh, I think I see your confusion now. If you leave the second argument out of `system.file` then it returns just the path to the folder, whereas in your example since you specify the file name (e.g. `xxx.csv`) then it only returns a single file at a time. So by coupling it with `list.files()` you get all the files rather than one at a time. Does that clarify?