# How to use an R package's own data when writing a vignette

Tags: r

I have written most of an R package and now wish to write a vignette that uses my own data, that is already in the package. The data is correctly stored as `my_data.Rda` in the `Data` folder, and when the package is loaded I can access it in the Console, for instance by using `data(my_data)`.

My problem comes when, using `usethis::use_vignette("my_vignette")` , I  want to include something like this (much more complex in practice, of course) in the vignette:

> The mean of my_data is given by

````
```{r} data(my_data)
mean(my_data)
```
````

When I knit the vignette I get the message

> "Error in assert_engine(is_numeric, x, .xname = get_name_in_parent(x),
>   :    object 'my_data' not found"

I have looked at this post: [How to add external data file into developing R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915385/how-to-add-external-data-file-into-developing-r-package) but that addresses **external** data.

What am I doing wrong?

I have created a minimal R package with the relevant Rmd file in the vignettes folder. [link to Github](https://github.com/jgcolman/mre/blob/master/mre/vignettes/my_vignette.Rmd)

Comment: Is this on github or anything? It would be much easier to help with a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) Ideally it would be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @MrFlick I am attempting to make a reproducible example package available on Github, but my question is actually perfectly general. I have a package that I have written, it contains data, I want to use that data in a vignette to be written in knitr, but knitr works in its own environment that does not contain my package's data. What do I do?

Comment: Just looked at your vignette. Might be worth putting `library(my_package)` at the start of it ...

Comment: It worked without doing that. Besides, I read in Hadley's  R Packages book that "...when building a package you should never use [library] inside a package". And I think that writing a vignette counts as being inside a package. Anyway, it turns out not to be needed.

Comment: I meant at the start of your vignette, not inside your package; I think you'll find your packages functions aren't available if you don't load your package into your vignette's session

Comment: For example, you have a function called `hello` in your basic package. Have a check whether this function is available to your vignette by adding a code block that calls `hello()` into your current vignette. The vignette can't be knitted if you don't also add `library(mre)` at the start of the vignette. The Wickham book is right however, your package code (stuff in `R/` or `tests/` etc) should not use `library()`.

Comment: Yes. I agree that the package must be loaded. I hesitated to load it in the Rmd document itself and therefore called library at the start of the session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are supposed to use

```
data(my_dataset, package = "my_package")
```

to load your package's data into the session where your vignette is built.

Could you confirm that your datasets are stored inside the `./data` directory of your package as `*.rda` files

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Works perfectly. Many thanks.